# Passing JSONP header's data parameter to AJAX request in another file

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have an AJAX request in function in another file. I need to pass json parameters to this request. Here are sample params which work in my ajax:

```
{firstName : name, lastName: sname, email : email, password : pass},
```

I would like to pass data as a function's parameter. I tried to pass it as a string param, but my function recognise it, and sends as a string. Which does not work.

My function with ajax request:

```
function ajax(url,contentType,data)
{  
    $.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});

console.log("Starting AJAX");

$.ajax({                                                                   
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'GET',
    url: url, 
    callback: 'jsonpCallback',
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
    jsonp: '_jsonp',
    data: data, 
    scriptCharset: "utf-8",
    contentType: contentType,
    dataType: 'jsonp json',
    timeout : 5000,

    success: success,
    error: error,
});
console.log('AJAX done');
}
```

I tried this:

```
ajaxRegister('http://lalal/register','application/json',data);

ajaxRegister('http://lalal/register','application/json','{firstName : name, lastName: sname, email : email, password : pass}');
```

The point is that when I put this sample json as a data parameter of the request, it works. I want to be flexible and be able to put any json in parameter and send it as a request's param.

Comment: Try data = JSON.parse(data); inside the function

Comment: The point is that when I put this sample json as a data parameter of the request, it works. I want to be flexible and be able to put any json in parameter and send it as a request's param. Parsing variables to json then json to variables to pass this variables back to json doesn't make sense. But thanks for answer, my question wasn't detailed enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is passing parameters in " ". It helped, but was not necesserly when locally adding  data.